# Store a variable in a external file

Tags: php

How can I store a variable in an external file?
Heres the code:

index.php:

```
<?php
$info=file('sites/test.php')
$titel=trim($info[1]);

echo $title;
?>
```

sites/test.php:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

What I would like index.php to output:

```
line1
```

I cant use `include_once`, because I only want the first line from sites/test.php

Comment: `$titel` !== `$title`

Comment: Can you explain it in antoher way??

Comment: @MarkBaker, Amazing eagle eyes :P

Comment: You're setting the variable `$titel` but echoing the variable `$title`..... look at the spelling

Comment: You're also extracting `$info[1]` which is the __second__ line from file.... array offsets are numbered from `0`, so you want `$info[0]` for the first line

Comment: also missing a `;` at line 2

Comment: Can some one make an example how index.php shall look and an example how sites/test.php shall look???

Comment: @KaareZ, Are you sure you are not trolling us ? ;)

Comment: Trolling? Why do you think that?

Comment: Because everything was pretty clearly explained by Mark and TouchPad. Did you atleast try modifying your code like what they said ?

Comment: Please some one help me!

Comment: I added the `;`, and I changed $info[1] to $info[0] It dosent helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoonfeeding, I know:

```
<?php
$info=file('sites/test.php');
$title=trim($info[0]);

echo $title;
?>
```

Comment: +1 for the silver spoon feed :)

Comment: And how shall the sites/test.php look???

Comment: @KaareZ, Like as it should. You don't need to modify that.

Comment: So just the "variable" at first line?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
$d=explode("\n", file_get_contents('sites/test.php'));
echo $d[0];
```

Comment: Enclose `sites/test.php` under quotes.